how to resolve the issue "Error message "error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported""
Trying to build a pipeline using Azure devops pipeline but ran into the issue

Error : 0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported.


npm version: 10.8.2
node version: v18.20.5
openssl version: OpenSSL 1.1.1w  11 Sep 2023
Agent version: 4.248.0
nuget installer version: 1.247.1

how can I resolve this issue?

Tried adding set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider didn't work

Somewhere you are picking up a version of OpenSSL more recent that 1.1.1w. That error message only occurs in OpenSSL 3.x

If it's a script inside package.json you can try:
"build": "export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider; REST OF YOUR COMMAND"

Or try to add a .npmrc file with
node-options=--openssl-legacy-provider

